# using http post to check session and redirect

Tags: php, angularjs, session

I am still new to angularjs and trying to understand the concept. i have a working solution but i just need to make sure this is a secure way of doing it. i have a `$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(){}` which sends a http post to a php file, this checks to see if it has session data and returns "1" being true and "0" being false. if false then i perform a `$state.go('login');` which redirects to login page. This works exactly how i wish it to but just would like some further knowledge if this is secure enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are several others way of authenticating the session data, your approach is fine as well.

Enclose the `$on` in `app.run` method and check if user is on login page then avoid the `$http` call.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next, nextParams, prev, prevParams) {

        //Check if already on login page do not check session
        if (next.name === 'login') {
            return;
        }

        //$http call to check session
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> This works exactly how i wish it to but just would like some further knowledge if this is secure enough.

When working with javascript or angular or any other `SPA` frameworks, forget about sessions. It's better using `token based authentication` system that provides you a lot of benefits, more security and more scalability.

There is a very good example [here](https://devdactic.com/restful-api-user-authentication-2/). It covers almost all aspects of token base auth that you need. Although it's for `ionic`, but doesn't matter. Ionic is built on the top of the angular.